# Modifying rindex in C

Tags: c, string

I'm programming in C (Linux OS). I need to use rindex for finding last occurence of a char specified as function argument.

```
char * rindex (const char *string, char c);
```

It works fine though I get warnings:

```
conflicting types for built-in function ‘rindex’ [enabled by default]
```

But if I include a `string.h` header. It gives error,

```
conflicting types for ‘rindex’
```

because there rindex is defined as,

```
char * rindex (const char *string, int c);
```

But I need to use it as char and also use the string.h for string operations. Is there any possibility? Kindly guide me.

Comment: If you must use rindex, use the standard declaration. The char parameter will be converted to an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 7th Edition UNIX™, there were two functions `index()` and `rindex()` that are respectively equivalent to the standard C functions `strchr()` and `strrchr()`, give or take `const` (which didn't exist when those functions were defined, any more than prototypes existed; there wasn't even C with Classes back then).

You're running foul of the backwards-compatible declarations of the function `rindex()`.  The names `index()` and `rindex()` are archaic, but you can't use them blithely in your own code.  Choose a different function name.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about strrchr. I used it now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* include standard string */
#include <string.h>
/* alias standard rindex to rindex_std */
#define rindex rindex_std
/* include your OS defined strings.h */
#include <strings.h>
```

This will solve the conflict.